# Sending sms in jsp

Tags: jsp, service, sms

I am trying to send bulk sms to my clients mobile phone through www.mysmsmynthra.com. Iam using the following code,
response.sendRedirect("http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&sendername=xxxx&mobileno=xxxx&message=xxxx");

When using response.sendRedirect() it send the messege succesfully.
My problem is i have to return to my homepage after the succesfull messege sending.Is there any other methods

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sendRedirect, you should make a GET/POST request to your SMS provider, (with HttpURLConnection for example), and then redirect to your homepage when you get your response back.